# panic: runtime error: index out of range [-1]

Tags: go

when I try to solve the leetcode problem of `118. Pascal's Triangle` https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/

it occured strange bug. Below the code can pass OJ.

```golang
func generate(numRows int) [][]int {
    res := [][]int{}
    for i := 0; i < numRows; i++ {
        row := []int{}
        for j := 0; j < i+1; j++ {
            if j == 0 || j == i {
                row = append(row, 1)
            } else if i > 1 {
                row = append(row, res[i-1][j-1] + res[i-1][j])
            }
        }
        res = append(res, row)
    }
    return res
}
```

But the code I write like this and it occur panic, but the basic logic is same.

```golang
func generate(numRows int) [][]int {
    res := [][]int{}
    for i := 0; i < numRows; i++ {
        row := []int{}
        for j := 0; j < i+1; j++ {
            if j == 0 || j == i {
                row = append(row, 1)
            }
            if i > 1 {
                row = append(row, res[i-1][j-1] + res[i-1][j])
            }
        }
        res = append(res, row)
    }
    return res
}
```

I used if else if structure, it works fine, but I use 2 if condition judgment error.

In fact, their logic is the same, but why the error? I would be grateful if you could solve this problem. Good lcuk for you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use 2 `if` conditions in the second version, while in the first version you have an `if else`.

> but the basic logic is same

No, the logic is not the same. The result is that you try to do `j-1` when `j` is 0.

If you have 2 if conditions like this, the program will enter both blocks individually if their respective condition is met.

```golang
if j == 0 || j == i {
    row = append(row, 1)
}
// if j is 0 you still enter this block as long as i > 1
if i > 1 {
    row = append(row, res[i-1][j-1] + res[i-1][j])
}
```

You could use `continue` to skip this section, if the first `if` is met.

```golang
if j == 0 || j == i {
    row = append(row, 1)
    // continue with the next iteration
    continue
}
if i > 1 {
    row = append(row, res[i-1][j-1] + res[i-1][j])
}
```

That said, using the `if else` in the first version of your code seems reasonable. I am not sure why you would want to change it.

Comment: Thank you for your patient explanation! The first version is the reference solution, and the second version is my solution. It seems that I don't have a good handle on boundary conditions. Best wishes!